# How to get remote ip through Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

I am new to Vapor, and trying to get remote IP. Have anyone succeeded doing that? I have checked the request headers, but nothing related to ip showed up. I can't figure it out, so is there any round way I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that from the request object.

```
print(req.peerAddress)
```